NGINX CORS Issue : Fetch API cannot load http://mymapserveraddress/protomaps.pmtiles due to access control checks
I'm getting this errors message:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin cannot contain more than one origin.
Fetch API cannot load http://mymapservername/protomaps.pmtiles due to access control checks.
Failed to load resource: Access-Control-Allow-Origin cannot contain more than one origin.
Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: Load failed

This is /etc/nginx/sites-available/default configuration :
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;

server_name myservername;

# SSL configuration
#
# listen 443 ssl default_server;
# listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
#
# Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
# See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
#
# Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
# See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
#
# Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
# Don't use them in a production server!
#
# include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

#root /var/www/html;

root /srv/myworldmap/html;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
#index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

index index.html;

#server_name _;

location / {
# First attempt to serve request as file, then
# as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

# pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
# include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
#
# # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
# fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
# # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
# fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
#location ~ /\.ht {
# deny all;
#}

add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*" always;
}

This is the content of /srv/myworldmap/html folder :
root@vmi1102187:~# ls -lah /srv/myworldmap/html/
total 115G
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Aug 30 16:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Aug 27 18:54 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.5K Aug 27 23:09 index.html
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4.0K Aug 27 23:03 node_modules
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.5K Aug 27 23:03 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 52 Aug 27 23:03 package.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 115G Aug 28 01:11 protomaps.pmtiles
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 82K Aug 27 19:30 style.json

/srv/myworldmap/html/index.html :
<html>
<head>
<title>PMTiles MapLibre Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/maplibre-gl@4.5.0/dist/maplibre-gl.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/maplibre-gl@4.5.0/dist/maplibre-gl.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pmtiles@3.0.6/dist/pmtiles.js"></script>
<style>
body {
margin: 0;
}
#map {
height:100%; width:100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
// add the PMTiles plugin to the maplibregl global.
let protocol = new pmtiles.Protocol();
maplibregl.addProtocol("pmtiles", protocol.tile);

let PMTILES_URL = "protomaps.pmtiles";

const p = new pmtiles.PMTiles(PMTILES_URL);

// this is so we share one instance across the JS code and the map renderer
protocol.add(p);

// we first fetch the header so we can get the center lon, lat of the map.
p.getHeader().then(h => {
const map = new maplibregl.Map({
container: 'map',
zoom: h.maxZoom-13,
center: [h.centerLon, h.centerLat],
style: 'style.json'
});
})
</script>
</body>
</html>

How to make these errors message:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin cannot contain more than one origin.
Fetch API cannot load http://mymapserveraddress/protomaps.pmtiles due to access control checks.
Failed to load resource: Access-Control-Allow-Origin cannot contain more than one origin.
Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: Load failed

disappear and make the map visible?
Raphy

I solved the issue thanks to these indications:
https://github.com/smellman/pmtiles-example?tab=readme-ov-file#cors-settings-in-nginx
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default :
  ##
  # You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
  # of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
  # https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
  # https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
  # https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
  #
  # In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
  # leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
  # updated by the nginx packaging team.
  #
  # This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
  # applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
  # available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
  #
  # Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
  ##
  
  # Default server configuration
  #
  server {
          #listen 80 default_server;
          #listen [::]:80 default_server;
  
          server_name myservername;
  
          # SSL configuration
          #
          # listen 443 ssl default_server;
          # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
          #
          # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
          # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
          #
          # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
          # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
          #
          # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
          # Don't use them in a production server!
          #
          # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;
  
          #root /var/www/html;
  
          root /srv/myworldmap/html;
  
          # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
          #index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
  
          index index.html;
  
          #server_name _;
  
          location / {
                  # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                  # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  
                  autoindex on;
                  autoindex_exact_size off;
                  autoindex_localtime on;
  
                  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" always;
                  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
                  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
                  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,Range,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;
  
                  if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                      # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
                      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" always;
                      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,Range,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;
                      add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                      add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                      add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                      return 204;
                  }
  
          }
  
          # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
          #
          #location ~ \.php$ {
          #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
          #
          #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
          #       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
          #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
          #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
          #}
  
          # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
          # concurs with nginx's one
          #
          #location ~ /\.ht {
          #       deny all;
          #}
  }
  
  
  # Virtual Host configuration for example.com
  #
  # You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
  # to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
  #
  #server {
  #       listen 80;
  #       listen [::]:80;
  #
  #       server_name example.com;
  #
  #       root /var/www/example.com;
  #       index index.html;
  #
  #       location / {
  #               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  #       }
  #}

